# how to create web socket to consume mapmyindia API

Tags: c#, api, websocket-sharp

I am new in websocket so my task is to create websocket sample for consuming mapmyindia API websocket will return information of vichal details so please help me to consume this API into websocket ..
Really apricate your work.

Comment: I assume you want to parsse and response from an HTTP Request.  You can either parse the string response in code or use a Controller to process the response.  Usually the response is either JSON or XML.  You need to provice more info for us to help

Comment: i am confused will you please provide me sample ...

Comment: Start here :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: yes i will use link like ws://localhost/getLiveData and after that it will hit inter API which i have set it than will get it values.

Comment: So the API is a Web Service.  You send a request to a URL and then get a response back. the response is probably a HTML formatted string which you have to parse.